# New data frame based on links between observations in existing data frame in R

Tags: r

I am working on a data frame that looks something like this:

Df.1:

```
“Ind. Name”          “Ind. ID”         “Inst”     “Inst. ID”
J. Smith             12345               A           532
K. Kapplan           12346               A           532
A. Lindt             12347               A           532
B. Johnson           12348               B           761
E. Pitt              12349               B           761
S. Mathews           12351               C           890
P. Rawles            12351               C           890    
P. Right             12352               C           890
O. Stray             12353               C           890
```

I need to create a function that allows me to have something like this as a result:

Df.Result:

```
“Ind. Name” “Ind.ID”  “Linked Ind.” “Linked Ind.ID” “Inst” “Inst.ID”
  J. Smith    12345    K. Kapplan        12346         A      352
  J. Smith    12345    A. Lindt          12347         A      352
  K. Kapplan  12346    J. Smith          12345         A      352   
  K. Kapplan  12346    A. Lindt          12347         A      352
  A. Lindt    12347    J. Smith          12345         A      352
  A. Lindt    12347    K. Kapplan        12346         A      352
  B. Johnson  12348    E. Pitt           12349         B      761
  E. Pitt     12349    B. Johnson        12348         B      761
  S. Mathews  12351    P. Rawles         12351         C      890
  S. Mathews  12351    P. Right          12352         C      890
  S. Mathews  12351    O. Stray          12353         C      890
  P. Rawles   12351    P. Right          12352         C      890
  P. Rawles   12351    S. Mathews        12351         C      890   
  P. Rawles   12351    O. Stray          12353         C      890
  P. Right    12352    O. Stray          12353         C      890
  P. Right    12352    P. Rawles         12351         C      890
  P. Right    12352    S. Mathews        12351         C      890   
  O. Stray    12353    P. Right          12352         C      890
  O. Stray    12353    P. Rawles         12351         C      890
  O. Stray    12353    S. Mathews        12351         C      890
```

Essentially I need a data frame that reflects how "Ind. Names" are linked by shared "Inst.". I am very new at R and I have tried several methods, including separating Df.1 into data frames for separate "Inst" and then applying the following functions:

```
My_function <- function(y){
Inst <- subset(Df.1, grepl(y, Df.1$`Inst.Id`))
+ return(Inst)
+ }

my_list <- c("A", "B", "C")

for(i in my_list){
Inst <- My_function(i)
assign(paste("Inst", i, sep = "."), Inst)
}
```

And then obtaining the links based on:

```
My_function2 <- function(x){
Df.C <- data.frame("Ind. Name"= C$`Ind`[x], "Linked Ind.Id"= C$`Linked Ind.Id*`[-(x)], "Linked Ind."= C$`Linked Ind.`[-(x)], "Inst"="C","Inst.ID*"=890)
```

So that using a loop

```
for(i in 1:4){
Network <- My_function2(i)
assign(paste("Network", i, sep = ".")
```

Results in four data frames:

Network.1:

```
 “Ind. Name” “Ind.ID”  “Linked Ind.” “Linked Ind.ID” “Inst” “Inst.ID”
  S. Mathews  12351    P. Rawles         12351         C      890
  S. Mathews  12351    P. Right          12352         C      890
  S. Mathews  12351    O. Stray          12353         C      890
```

Network.2:

```
    “Ind. Name” “Ind.ID”  “Linked Ind.” “Linked Ind.ID” “Inst” “Inst.ID”
      P. Rawles   12351    P. Right          12352         C      890
      P. Rawles   12351    S. Mathews        12351         C      890   
      P. Rawles   12351    O. Stray          12353         C      890
```

Network.3:

```
     “Ind. Name” “Ind.ID”  “Linked Ind.” “Linked Ind.ID” “Inst” “Inst.ID”
      P. Right    12352    O. Stray          12353         C      890
      P. Right    12352    P. Rawles         12351         C      890
      P. Right    12352    S. Mathews        12351         C      890
```

Network.4:

```
     “Ind. Name” “Ind.ID”  “Linked Ind.” “Linked Ind.ID” “Inst” “Inst.ID”
      O. Stray    12353    P. Right          12352         C      890
      O. Stray    12353    P. Rawles         12351         C      890
      O. Stray    12353    S. Mathews        12351         C      890
```

Seeing as I have 4,000 different "Inst", and 8,000 "Ind.", this is of course very inefficient so I would appreciate any help or tips on how can this be achieved in a functional way in R

Thank you

Comment: It looks like what you want is to build a network structure. There are several packages to help with this so you don't have to do it from scratch, such as the aptly named `network`. I'm not great with networks, but I bookmarked this article recently to help with a project at work: https://www.jessesadler.com/post/network-analysis-with-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your main aim is to reproduce `Df.Result`. You can achieve this with a simple outer join using `dplyr::full_join`.

```
library(tidyverse);
full_join(df, df, by = "Inst") %>%
    filter(Ind..Name.x != Ind..Name.y)
#   Ind..Name.x Ind..ID.x Inst Inst..ID.x Ind..Name.y Ind..ID.y Inst..ID.y
#1     J. Smith     12345    A        532  K. Kapplan     12346        532
#2     J. Smith     12345    A        532    A. Lindt     12347        532
#3   K. Kapplan     12346    A        532    J. Smith     12345        532
#4   K. Kapplan     12346    A        532    A. Lindt     12347        532
#5     A. Lindt     12347    A        532    J. Smith     12345        532
#6     A. Lindt     12347    A        532  K. Kapplan     12346        532
#7   B. Johnson     12348    B        761     E. Pitt     12349        761
#8      E. Pitt     12349    B        761  B. Johnson     12348        761
#9   S. Mathews     12351    C        890   P. Rawles     12351        890
#10  S. Mathews     12351    C        890    P. Right     12352        890
#11  S. Mathews     12351    C        890    O. Stray     12353        890
#12   P. Rawles     12351    C        890  S. Mathews     12351        890
#13   P. Rawles     12351    C        890    P. Right     12352        890
#14   P. Rawles     12351    C        890    O. Stray     12353        890
#15    P. Right     12352    C        890  S. Mathews     12351        890
#16    P. Right     12352    C        890   P. Rawles     12351        890
#17    P. Right     12352    C        890    O. Stray     12353        890
#18    O. Stray     12353    C        890  S. Mathews     12351        890
#19    O. Stray     12353    C        890   P. Rawles     12351        890
#20    O. Stray     12353    C        890    P. Right     12352        890
```

Explanation: Perform an outer join of `df` with itself by `ID` and remove rows with identical `Ind.Name`s.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "'Ind. Name'         'Ind. ID'        'Inst'    'Inst. ID'
'J. Smith'             12345               A           532
'K. Kapplan'           12346               A           532
'A. Lindt'             12347               A           532
'B. Johnson'           12348               B           761
'E. Pitt'              12349               B           761
'S. Mathews'           12351               C           890
'P. Rawles'            12351               C           890
'P. Right'             12352               C           890
'O. Stray'             12353               C           890", header = T)
```